# Multiple activity on one button click

Tags: java, android, button

I have a problem with creating 2 activities for 1 button. I created a button and I managed to connect that button with one activity but I dont know how to add another activity to the same button.. What am I trying to do is that when we press on that button it will start playing animation (I managed to do that) but I also want it to send SMS to a specific number. I have code for that, but I dont know how to include / connect everything together.

Code from a button:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
```

Code from a imageview (animation):

```
<ImageView

    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:src="@drawable/keers" />
```

Code from main activity, for animation:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    running = false;

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(!running){
            ((AnimationDrawable) imageView.getDrawable()).start();
            running = true;}
        }
    }
    );
}
}
```

Now what I want to add for the same button is this :

```
public void sendText(View paramView)
{
    Toast.makeText(this, "SENT",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    SmsManager.getDefault().sendTextMessage("+3564245237",null,"1", null, null);
```

I'm not that experienced in programming, so it might be pretty easy for you guys.

Comment: well. you may be coping code from difference places. You have just to write sms sending code in your button click.

Comment: Im sorry but I dont really understand what you meant? I had this code for like 1year but I decided to upgrade my previous app so that it will look better, but now when I try to add this part of code for SMS its not working..

Answer (score 0):

Both actions seen to be fired by the same Button, so you may add both to the onClickListener

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View view) {
        if(!running){
        ((AnimationDrawable) imageView.getDrawable()).start();
        running = true;}
         Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "SENT",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //Or YourActivity.this
         SmsManager.getDefault().sendTextMessage("+3564245237",null,"1", null, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: So I tried to do that @Marcos Vasconcelos and when I debugged app there were 0 errors, and app opened just like it should, but when I click on that button app shuts down for some reason? Error message is: App has stopped working.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Look into the logcat console of the Android studio (at Android Monitor very down there) and see the exception message, but my guess is that you need  SMS permission in manifest, also the makeText(this is not resolved there for a OnClickListener, use a context

Comment: Okay so I removed Toast command because that is not rly important, and I added "<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/> " to my manifest file. I debugged app again and this are errors from Logcat: https://gyazo.com/d0570f7e29417c5274a6928e4a276140 ... if you dont trust this gyazo link let me know and I will use other screenshot program.

Comment: If you running the code into a Android 4.4+ you need to ask for explicit permissions in runtime. This is a different question and you can find the answers over internet

Comment: Okay so I am missing only explicit permissions in runtime?

Comment: yes, for example call only Toast instead of Sms there, you will see it working

Comment: Sure, please leave a upvote if I helped you or accept the answer if it solved your problem

Comment: sure thing! I only have one more question about this explicit permissions in runtime.. So I only need to add commands in manifest file or also in mainactivity?

Comment: Yes, on mainactivity. https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: Okay thanks! I will try to figure it out what I need. :)

Comment: If you willing to fast results, you can also set targetSdk of your application (gradle) to 21, so runtime permissions are not needed